# Why is "debugger" not a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger

If I have a JavaScript file running in my browser with the developer tools open, and the file has the line `debugger;`, the browser will pause the program and show some things like the call stack and defined variables.

This seems strange. Simply mentioning the name of something in JavaScript usually doesn't have side effects. I would think that I would need to add parentheses to call it like a function.

Why is `debugger` implemented this way?

I am pretty sure it is a reserved keyword in the language, and not a built-in function like `parseInt`, but I'm wondering about the rationale behind designing the language this way.

Comment: It’s a keyword and a statement, not a name. Since it does something pretty special, I think implementing it as a keyword (instead of something like `console.break()`? `debugger.break()`?) is fine.

Comment: To make everyone's life easy debugging

Comment: What about using "var debugger;"? Would that fix the problem?

Comment: I tried `var debugger;` and got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token debugger`.

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: `typeof` and `void` also don't take parentheses, so it's not without precedent.

Comment: "_mentioning the name of something in JavaScript usually doesn't have side effects_" How about `break`, `continue`, `return` ..? They are just similar keywords as `debugger`.

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi `debugger` is a keyword; `var debugger;` makes as much sense as `var while;` — it doesn’t work.

Comment: I am not trying to solve a specific problem, nor is there any specific code example I can give. I am running the `debugger` statement and it is behaving like it usually does. I am just curious as to why `debugger` is implemented this way.

Comment: This is a question which probably is not answerable at SO, you should ask [TC39](https://www.ecma-international.org/memento/TC39.htm) about the reasons.

Comment: As Teemu said, you should probably bring the language designers’ attention to this question. Compared to some other things that could be implemented as functions (by users!) though, like `instanceof`, `void`, `new`, … `debugger` is pretty magical. And if you make it a function, you have to decide where to put it. And it was already a reserved word in the first edition of ECMAScript.

Comment: I'll consider the advice given here to ask the language designers, although I will not promise that I'll do it any time soon.

Comment: @EliasZamaria In case you'll ask, and get an answer, could you please post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Teemu, sure. I'll keep this question in mind.

Comment: There are lots of questions here about why the language authors did things a particular way. Most are closed as too broad or opinionated. "*Simply mentioning the name of something in JavaScript usually doesn't have side effects*". What about "use strict"? Other one–word statements like *continue* and *break*? Or those that can be one–word statements like *return* and *yeild*?